# Comando que substitua time.sleep?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

estou fazendo um programa que faz a detecção de cores e formatos de objetos com uma câmera, ao ser reconhecido o formato e a cor configurada, o programa faz o controle das GPIOS no qual eu conectei um modulo relé.
O problema que estou tendo é que quando uso o comando time.sleep para manter o modulo relé ligado, o mesmo faz com que todo o programa congele.

Aqui está o trecho que estou tentando resolver:

```
if len(approx) == 4:    
  gpio.output(40 , 0)
  time.sleep(10)
  gpio.output(40, 1)
  time.sleep(5)
  cv2.putText(frame, "QUADRADO", (x, y), font, 1, (0, 255, 255) )
```

Estou utilizando opencv e todo controle é feito por um Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Agradeço pela atenção amigos.

Comment: A documentação oficial diz que a função sleep(): `Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.` Então você terá que utilizar o multi threading... para usar a função sleep. Ou quando um microcontrolador não possui multi threading, o que é utilizado é se `tempo_agora - tempo_inicio/referência == tempo_desejado`, então realizar tal comando.

Answer (score -2):

Cara assim funcionou para mim, da uma olhada pra ver se funciona

```
from time import sleep
print("Faz algo aqui")
##dorme em segundos
sleep(1)
print("Faz outra coisa aqui")
```

Comment: Olá João obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Fiz os seguintes comandos:

from time import sleep

pin_status = gpio.OUTPUT(40, 0)
print(pin_status)
sleep(2) #segundos

Porém continua a mesma coisa o programa continua parando, mas de qualquer forma agreço pela ajuda!!